# access directshow in quicktime and or processing

Tags: directshow, processing, quicktime

Please excuse my ignorance, im very new to windows.
Windows 7 64bit
Point Grey Grasshopper 2 GigE Camera

I have a gigE Camera that I want to use in processing. In processing I can use any camera that shows up as a quicktime device. But the gigE camera does not show up in the camera list.

The camera is registered as a directShow device.

Is there a way to either get the camera to be available as a quicktime device, or use the directShow device in processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [effectively] primary video capture API in Windows is DirectShow. If you have it available as DirectShow device then you certainly can get video and process it. As you did not ask specific questions about processing, perhaps this should be a good starting point for you:

- [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717422.aspx) Samples in $(WindowsSdk)\Samples\multimedia\directshow
- [DirectShow Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN